# Deleting and reformatting certain characters in a string using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc that has placeholders for employee terminology. Example:

> Once <<a/an employee, team member, associate, etc.>> submits their
> time card..

I'm creating a script that will replace this placeholder with the correct term that the user will enter into a prompt. Here's what I have so far:

```
    function empTerm() {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    var termResponse = ui.prompt("Employee Terminology", "Type in the partner's terminology for their employees. Use the single form with no capital letters with 'a/an' at the beginning \n Ex: 'an associate', 'a team member', etc.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var termButton = termResponse.getSelectedButton();
    if (termButton == ui.Button.OK) {
      var newTerm = termResponse.getResponseText();
      var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
      body.replaceText("<<a/an employee, associate, team member, etc.>>", newTerm);
    }
    }
```

My issue is that I'm not sure how to account for the different formats that are needed, like "a" or "an" depending on the term, as well as capitalizing and adding plural versions. So for example, here are some of the different versions I would need:

- <<a/an employee, associate, team member, etc.>> would turn into "an associate".
- <<employees, associates, team members, etc.>> would turn into "associates".
- <<Employee, Associate, Team member, etc.>> would turn into "Associate".
- <<A/An employee, associate, team member, etc.>> would turn into "An associate".

The term varies based on the employer we're working with, but I'm hoping there's some kind of regex that I could use to add an "s" on the end, and capitalize, etc. (depending on the case, as mentioned in the bulleted list above), especially because the user will only input one version in the prompt.

So for example, the user would input "an associate", then the script would go through the doc and replace the variables with different versions of the input (Associates, Associate, An associate, an associate).

I could have the user input all the possible versions, which would make the script a lot easier to build, but that seems a bit tedious.

There's [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/editing-styling#inserting_and_deleting_text) in the documentation, which is the closest thing I've found, but I'm not sure if it would work in my situation.

Would appreciate any help on how I can account for these different versions!

Comment: "but I'm hoping there's some kind of regex that I could use to add an "s" on the end in some cases" Please add a sample of such cases. Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use `<<tags>>` that tell what is expected, and replace each one separately, like this:

- `<<roleSingular>>`: replace with `an employee`, `an associate`, or `a team member`
- `<<rolePlural>>`: replace with `employees`, `associates`, or `team members`
- `<<roleSingularCap>>`: replace with `An employee`, `An associate`, or `A team member`
- `<<rolePluralCap>>`: replace with `Employees`, `Associates`, or `Team members`

You may want to try [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat) instead of writing your own code. For other options, choose **Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for  `mail merge`.